# Obsidian pillar with lapis block on top

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Is there any deeper purpose in these obsidian pillars?
[image]

They appear most often in the twilight forest but I think I have seen them also in the the overworld.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they are purely decoration. Pillars in the overworld that look similar (but smaller) are totems from Thaumcraft, but in the Twilight Forest these are just part of the scenery.

Comment: The difference is that these ones have an lapis block on top and are made of standard obsidian, not totem blocks.

Comment: I don't think these are thaumcraft totems. thuam totems are made of the totem block; not obsidian and certainly not lapiz.

Comment: @JLaBella Yes, this is what I wanted to say. These pillars I described are made of standard obsidian blocks while the totems use totem blocks from thaumcraft.